# Android show one layout element over another

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, slidingpanelayout

I know this type of problem already discussed here so many times . But in my case none of them working for me .  I am using [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) in my project with navigation drawer.  The problem is sliding panel layout always showing over navigation drawer , but what I  want is reverse . Here is the current condition

[image]

As you can see I can't see the navigation drawer items . Sliding panel layout hides the navigation drawer .

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
    sothree:umanoOverlay="false"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
    sothree:umanoParalaxOffset="100dp"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp">


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawerMainActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">



        <FrameLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/containerView">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:id="@+id/toolBar"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                />

        </FrameLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            />

     </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


    <!-- SLIDING LAYOUT -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dragView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"

        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/slide"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_hide"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/hide"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFCCCC">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/image" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

How can I solve this problem ? So that navigation drawer always comes top over sliding panel layout .

Comment: Have you you tried setting the `DrawerLayout` as the root element?

Comment: @PPartisan thanks , it is working now.

Comment: @PPartisan would you please post your comment as a answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `DrawerLayout` as the root element, instead of your `SlidingUpPanelLayout`

Answer (score 1):

To set the Z-axis you have to order the tree. From the documentation

[View.html#Drawing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Drawing)

> The tree is largely recorded and drawn in order, with parents drawn
>   before (i.e., behind) their children, with siblings drawn in the order
>   they appear in the tree. If you set a background drawable for a View,
>   then the View will draw it before calling back to its onDraw() method.
>   The child drawing order can be overridden with custom child drawing
>   order in a ViewGroup, and with setZ(float) custom Z values} set on
>   Views.

So basically set the Drawerlayout as last.